# How do I get the URL from context.xml resource

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I am using a JNDI DataSouce with Tomcat.

my context.xml for java web app has a resource ta that looks like this :

```
<Resource
        name="jdbc/dbv1RW" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbv1"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username="root" password="root"
 />
```

And I fetch the data source in my java class like this :

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
dataSource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/dbv1RW");
```

**How can I get the URL of the data source without establishing the connetion with the data source(i.e. without calling the get connection method) ?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to printout what is the real implementation of the returned data source. If the implementation exposes the parameters then you can cast it to its real type and access them. It will be implementation (server) specific.

Comment: When I print it I am getting : 
createConnection current Data Source org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource@f67ef4

Comment: Check the source http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html. There is getUrl method there

Comment: I am getting an exception saying :javax.sql.datasource cannot be cast into org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Comment: You just wrote that it had this actual type. Did you wrote System.out.println(dataSource.getClass().getName()) after you got it from the context?

Comment: In My server log I am getting this, when is simply put datasource in the log as an Object that is.